# Loading data takes too much time by using pipeline in lookup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have database with more than 5000 students and 300 employees with 1 MB document size each and I am using below lookup code in order to get certificates of students and employees.

```
$step1 =  ['$lookup' => [
        'from' => 'EmployeesTbl',
        'let' => ['certificateTypeEmployee' => '$_id'],
        'pipeline' => [
            ['$unwind' => '$CertificatesDetails'],
            ['$match' => ['$expr' => ['$eq' => ['$CertificatesDetails.documentType', '$$certificateTypeEmployee']]]],
            ['$project' => ['_id' => 1.0, 'FirstName' => 1.0, 'LastName' => 1.0, 'EmployeeNumber' => 1.0, 'CertificatesDetails' => 1.0]]
        ],
        'as' => 'employeeArray'
    ]];        


    $step2 =  ['$lookup' => [
      'from' => 'studentTbl',
      'let' => ['certificateTypeStudent' => '$_id'],
      'pipeline' => [
        ['$unwind' => '$certificates_details'],
        ['$match' => ['$expr' => ['$eq' => ['$certificates_details.documentType', '$$certificateTypeStudent']]]],
        ['$project' => ['_id' => 1.0, 'first_name' => 1.0, 'last_name' => 1.0, 'uploadsFolder' => 1.0, 'certificates_details' => 1.0, 'registration_temp_perm_no' => 1.0]]
      ],
      'as' => 'studentArray'
    ]];               
            $step3 =  [
                '$project' => [
                  "_id" => 1.0,
                  "UsedFor" => 1.0,
                  "Type" => 1.0,
                  "Code" => 1.0,
                  "Description" => 1.0,
                  "schoolId" => 1.0,
                  "employeeArray" => 1.0,
                  "studentArray" => 1.0
                ]
             ];

    $step4 =  array(
        '$match' => [
            'schoolId' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->schoolId),
            '$or' => [
                ['employeeArray' => ['$not' => ['$size' => 0]]],
                ['studentArray' => ['$not' => ['$size' => 0]]]
            ]
        ]
    ); 

    $step5 = [];

     ....

    $cursor = iterator_to_array($this->db->certificateTypeTbl->aggregate(array($step1, $step2, $step3, $step4, $step5, $step6, $step7, $step8, $step9, $step10, $step11, $step12, $step13, $step14, $step15, $step16, $step17, $step18, $searchCommand, $sortCommand, $skipCommand), $allowDiskCommand));
```

The above code is fetching data correctly but the lookup in the pipeline is causing too much time to load data... Please suggest some alternating ways in order to speed up loading time.

Comment: well if you have 18 lookups with unwind within each, it's gonna take time

Comment: I have updated my code in the above question... Please verify it once again. Also Please tell me, is there any alternation for the $unwind command in mongo DB which will make the query faster?

Comment: Nida, it doesn't work this way. There is no optimisation for individual operators. It's like asking how to fix an overflow issues for `*` operation.  Query performance optimisation requires at least the whole pipeline, structure and basic stats on all collections involved, results of `.explain()`  command, and considering length of the pipeline, likely explanations of what you are going to achieve, as it must be quite long to analyse and reverse-engineer requirements from the code.

Comment: I highly suspect that your pipeline can be made **much** more efficient - unwinding entire collections for each processed document is very expensive.  If you show some example "minimized" documents in each collection with the desired output, I'm confident a more efficient pipeline can be offered.